# Using xpath to grab a particular section

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have the following xml and I'm trying to grab the following element but not sure how it is done that is near the bottom:

```
Cashless catering Primary School
```

Can anyone suggest how to grab this using xpath by using the refinement="Pupil" tag/attribute?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="no"?>
<IntegrationExport xmlns="urn:NSCP-Integration-Export-v1">
<Data>
<Citizen messageId="331013" id="43018" authorisingId="1" messageTypeId="1" smartcardId="12345680201327582" serviceId="57" issuer="Primary School">
  <Services>
    <Service application="ISO File Handler" refinement="ISO File Handler" />
    <Service application="CCDA" refinement="CCDA">
      <Item name="SMARTCARDID">12345680201327582</Item>
      <Item name="IIN" />
      <Item name="CARDNO" />
      <Item name="ISSUE">7</Item>
      <Item name="TITLE" />
      <Item name="FORENAME">Jon</Item>
      <Item name="INITIALS" />
      <Item name="SURNAME">Doe</Item>
      <Item name="NAME">Jon Doe</Item>
      <Item name="DOB">2004-11-04 00:00:00</Item>
      <Item name="GENDER">1</Item>
      <Item name="Ethnic Origin">White Other</Item>
      <Item name="Faith" />
      <Item name="SEN / Disability" />
      <Item name="Language" />
      <Item name="DOBVERIFIED">1</Item>
      <Item name="FLAT" />
      <Item name="HOUSE NUMBER/NAME" />
      <Item name="Street" />
      <Item name="Locality" />
      <Item name="Postal Town" />
      <Item name="County" />
      <Item name="POSTCODE" />
      <Item name="LOCAL AUTHORITY" />
      <Item name="RESIDENT">R</Item>
      <Item name="UPRN" />
      <Item name="HOME TEL" />
      <Item name="WORK TEL" />
      <Item name="MOBILE" />
      <Item name="EMAIL" />
      <Item name="Password" />
      <Item name="EXPIRY DATE">2017-09-01 00:00:00</Item>
      <Item name="Reward points">90</Item>
      <Item name="UPN">E301207408111</Item>
      <Item name="ParentPay ID">4292111</Item>
      <Item name="PayPoint Account No" />
      <Item name="YEARGROUP">3</Item>
      <Item name="FORMNAME">RED</Item>
      <Item name="Acknowledgement" />
      <Item name="USERID" />
      <Item name="REWARDS DATE" />
      <Item name="BARCODE">00100048123</Item>
      <Item name="MEMBER ID" />
      <Item name="LEISURECODE" />
      <Item name="LEISUREDATE" />
    </Service>
    <Service application="Special Needs" refinement="Special Needs">
      <Item name="CUSTOM MESSAGE">Placeholder message for special needs application.</Item>
      <Item name="SCREEN COLOUR">00</Item>
      <Item name="FONT">00</Item>
      <Item name="CHARACTER SIZE">00</Item>
      <Item name="SPEECH OUTPUT">00</Item>
    </Service>
    <Service application="Cashless catering Primary School" refinement="Pupil" />
    <Service application="Splash" refinement="Splash">
      <Item name="USERNAME" />
      <Item name="INITIAL PASSWORD" />
    </Service>
  </Services>
</Citizen>
```

Code

```
$endpoint = "http://111.222.11.200/someUrl.asmx?WSDL";
$client = new SoapClient($endpoint, array('trace' => 1));
$xml = $client->GetCitizenData($arrValues);
$xml = (string)$xml->GetCitizenDataResult;

$xml = preg_replace('/(<\?xml[^?]+?)utf-16/i', '$1utf-8', $xml);
$xml_element = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$nodes = $xml_element->xpath('/Citizen/Services/Service[@refinement="Pupil"]/@application');
```

When I dump the nodes array I get the following:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [application] => Cashless catering Primary School ) )
```

Comment: Please tell us what language/environment you use XPath in. Namespaces are handled differently depending on the library/ XPath engine.

Comment: this PHP - WAMP environment (although ultimately the code will be on a unix server)

Comment: Only partially answers my question; does that mean you wrote PHP code that evaluates XPath expressions? If so, please show it - and tag the question as such.

Comment: Show _all_ relevant PHP code, including the part where you fetch from a web URL, or parse an XML document from the file system; [a complete PHP script](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: added some additional PHP code

Comment: Much better. Now, since you're already getting `Cashless catering Primary School` as the result - what's wrong with this result? What _should_ the result look like?

Comment: I sussed it - 
var_dump($nodes[0]->application);exit;

This gets just the info I need... feel free for either of you guys to add the answer and i will accept as both your tips helped greatly

Comment: @MathiasMüller I was having issue just pulling the string 'Cashless catering Primary School' but was quite simple in the end.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, finally we have worked out<sup>1</sup> that you were already getting the correct results, as far as XPath is concerned; your path expression retrieves the correct node.

The only difficulty was that evaluating the path expression returns an *array*. When the whole array is dumped, you naturally get back more than the wanted string itself. Using

```
var_dump($nodes[application]);
```

will only dump the first item in this array:

```
string(32) "Cashless catering Primary School"
```

Using `reset()` would do something similar:

```
<?php
$array = array( application => 'Cashless catering Primary School');
echo reset($array);
?>
```

as would `array_values($array)[0]`.

---

But note that using the `SimpleXML` libraries of PHP and Java is discouraged in many contexts, because their behaviour can be surprising. In your specific case, one could be forgiven to expect that an XPath expression like

```
//Citizen
```

would not return anything, since those elements are in a *default namespace*. Usually, default namespaces need to be redeclared in PHP code, and made available to the XPath engine. But `SimpleXML` ignores default namespaces - which is "not so simple", really.

---

<sup>1</sup> This should teach you a lesson about writing good questions. For your future questions, please make sure to include all relevant information right away.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've registered an alias `x` for namespace `urn:NSCP-Integration-Export-v1`, to grab just the attribute "application":

```
//x:Citizen/x:Services/x:Service[@refinement='Pupil']/@application
```

**Edit**

If you aren't able to utlilize namespaces, you can use the namespace agnostic 'local-name()'. Note that I'm assuming that you have only one type of `Citizen` or `Service` in the same tree, which seems reasonable as your sample document references one namespace.

```
//*[local-name()='Citizen']//*[local-name()='Service' and @refinement='Pupil']/@application
```

Comment: I've not done.. could you elaborate on that.. i've never come across using aliases in xml/xpath

Comment: I've added a namespace agnostic variation, but use of strong namespaces is much better practice.